# looking for WCF basicHttpBinding https tutorial or samples

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, https

I am using VSTS 2008 + .Net 3.5 + C# to develop a console application as a WCF cient, and host WCF service in IIS 7.0 at server side (server using Windows Vista x64).

Currently, my WCF client and server works quite well with http. Now I want to add https support and still use basicHttpBinding. Any easy to learn tutorials? I do not want to make too much modification to my WCF client/server and want to find a way which involves minimal code change. :-)

BTW: for IIS server certificate, I want client side to accept all server certificate. And I just use https encryption feature.

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See those excellent articles:

- [Fundamentals of WCF Security](http://www.code-magazine.com/article.aspx?quickid=0611051&page=1)
- [p&p WCF Security Application Scenarios](http://blogs.msdn.com/jmeier/archive/2008/04/04/patterns-and-practices-wcf-security-application-scenarios.aspx)
- [MSDN Common Security Scenarios](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730301.aspx)
- [WCF Security Part 3 of 10](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article388-wcf-faq-part-3-%E2%80%93-10-security-related-faq.aspx)
- [WCF Security Guidance on Codeplex](http://wcfsecurity.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Application%20Scenarios) - basically covers everything there is, in great detail, sometimes almost a bit too much :-)

Marc

Comment: Very nice stuff, thanks Marc!

Answer (score 1):

```xml
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="defaultBasicHttpBinding">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<system.serviceModel>       
  <services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior" name="MyServiceName">       
      <endpoint address="https://XYZ.com/MyService.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="defaultBasicHttpBinding"
                contract="Axis.IServiceContract" />
      <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>               
          <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
            <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
          </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
      </behaviors>
    </service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Looks right to me in my arm chair.