# Soap Envelope Receiver in WindowsFormApplication Using HTTP in C#

Tags: c#, http, soap

I am new to SOAP, can any one please tell me how can i receive Soap Envelope using HTTP,
I have done receiving in TCP, where url for receiver is like

```
soap.tcp://localhost/receiver
```

i want to receive in http

```
http://localhost/receiver
```

can an one please guide me, if there is a configuration in app.config file please explain,

Comment: http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/how-to-consume-a-web-service/

Comment: Use WCF. See this answer for good reference to tutorials and background info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339517/looking-for-wcf-basichttpbinding-https-tutorial-or-samples

Comment: m not using WCF, nor any web service i am only sending envelops from asp.net applicaytion and want to receive that in WindowsFormApplicatio as http